# React hook is not working from event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React version: 16.8.2

```
const { useState } = React;

const Dropdown = ({
  options,
  onClick,
  selected,
}) => {
  const [showDropDown, setShowDropDown] = useState(false);

  function toggleDropDown() {
    setShowDropDown(v => !v);
  }

  function createOption(o) {
    return (
      <div
        key={o}
        className='drop-down__option'
        onClick={() => {
          onClick(o);
          toggleDropDown();  
          // The following isn't working either
          // setShowDropDown(false);
        }}
       >
        {o}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div
      onClick={toggleDropDown}
      className='drop-down'
    >
      <div>{selected}</div>
        {showDropDown && (
          <div className='drop-down__list'>
            {options.map(createOption)}
          </div>
        )}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);

  return (
    <Dropdown
      selected={selected}
      options={[0,1,2,3]}
      onClick={v=>{setSelected(v)}}
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

So, it's a simple `Dropdown`, when you click the container, it toggles the `Dropdown`.

> But the problem here is, after clicking one of the options, the option has been updated, but the `Dropdown` is not been closed.

So it appears `toggleDropDown();` in the following code has no effect.

```js
        onClick={() => {
          onClick(o);
          toggleDropDown();  
          // The following isn't working either
          // setShowDropDown(false);
        }}
```

A reproduce example can be found here: https://codepen.io/vensa-albertgao/pen/ommGZe

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in you code is that the `click` even on `dropdown` options was being propagated up to the parent where you call `toggleDropdown` again onClick and hence the toggling was happening twice causing it to not occur visibly. All you need is to stopPropagation on options click

```
const { useState } = React;

const Dropdown = ({
  options,
  onClick,
  selected,
}) => {
  const [showDropDown, setShowDropDown] = useState(false);

  function toggleDropDown() {
    console.log('called');
    setShowDropDown(v => { console.log(v); return !v});
  }

  function createOption(option) {
    return (
      <div
        key={option}
        className='drop-down__option'
        onClick={e => {
          e.stopPropagation();
          onClick(option);
          toggleDropDown();  
        }}
       >
        {option}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div
      onClick={toggleDropDown}
      className='drop-down'
    >
      <div>{selected}</div>
        {showDropDown && (
          <div className='drop-down__list'>
            {options.map(createOption)}
          </div>
        )}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);

  return (
    <Dropdown
      selected={selected}
      options={[0,1,2,3]}
      onClick={v=>{setSelected(v)}}
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

[Working demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zeeWdW)

Answer (score 1):

change `toggleDropDown` function to

```
function toggleDropDown() {
    setShowDropDown(!showDropDown);
}
```

forked the example

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XOOzaZ